# Simple LRU cache with an expiration time

Tags: java, performance, cache

How can I improve the performance of the code below?

```
package utils.session;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * <p>
 * A very simple LRU cache implementation, used for our server side session
 * management.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author royguo@abcdefg.com
 */
public class SessionCache {
  private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Entry> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  static class Entry {
    private final Object value;
    private final Long expiration;
    private Long lastUseTime;

    public Entry(Object value, Long expiration) {
      this.value = value;
      this.expiration = expiration;
      this.lastUseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
      return (lastUseTime + expiration) < System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public Object getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }

    public void updateUseTime() {
      this.lastUseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
  }

  static {
    /**
     * Scan our LRU cache every 30 minutes, remove expired keys.
     */
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          while (true) {
            for (String key : cache.keySet()) {
              if (cache.get(key).isExpired())
                cache.remove(key);
            }
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30));
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }).start();
  }

  /**
   * Put a new object into cache, and speicify its expiration time. Everytime we
   * get the object from cache, its expiration time would be updated.
   */
  public static void put(String key, Object value, Long expiration) {
    cache.put(key, new Entry(value, expiration));
  }

  /**
   * Get instance from cache, no need to be thread-safe.
   */
  public static Object get(String key) {
    Entry entry = cache.get(key);
    if (!entry.isExpired()) {
      entry.updateUseTime();
      return entry.getValue();
    } else {
      cache.remove(key);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would use a single HashMap holding a class with both Object and timestamp. This way you only need one get operation instead of two.

Comment: I don't see how it is _LRU_

Comment: @vnp, I've updated my code, please help to have a look, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I still don't see how it is LRU, but that's beside the point.

One obvious problem is a race between testing for `cache.get(key).isExpired()` and `cache.remove(key)` on the next line. It is very well possible for another thread to preempt right in between just to `get()` that object.

A thread performing `get()` would believe that it updated `useTime`, yet the entry would have been removed.

Depending on the use case, the consequences could be catastrophic, or harmless.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ConcurrentHashMap , I prefer you can use ConcurrentSkipListMap. Because its sorted map. You can fetch from `lastEntry` check the isExpired.

**Limitations:**

Sorting occurred based on key. So Please define new key object with existing String and expire time.